# How to add same layout multiple times during runtime;

Tags: android, android-layout

I want add issue layout multiple times during run time to an Linear layout I am using below code but layout coming only one time on the screen.please help i am designing e mail like app.based number of emails layout number also changes during run-time please help me.

```
for (int i=10;i<14;i++) {
LinearLayout lay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.veticaltoinsert);
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.issuelayout, null);
child.setId(i);
lay.addView(child);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the you are going to be displaying a list of emails, why not use a `ListView` with a custom adapter and layout for the for the emails being displayed in the list.

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView), it should help you out.

Comment: I am new android i dont know much how to use it

Comment: @rks use the tutorial I gave the link for. That is the right way of doing it and also the easier way of doing it.

Comment: And for more control and better animations and stuff, you can use RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

You need a listview or recyclerview here.
Using them you can define layout for a single item and can repeat it using adapters.

[Official tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)